# How to improve BSIS reading inside dynamic itab loop?

Tags: abap

I have a code as below, which takes more than 200 minutes to execute, could you help me to improve the performance.

This code is triggered at User Command. Say users select all records (about 300K records) at first level output for next level drill down report:

1. The dynamic internal table `<OI_TABLE>` has around 300K records with a field component called `BOX` marked as 'X' for those selected lines by the user.
2. The program reads the selected lines from the dynamic internal table (`<OI_TABLE>`), compare them to another standard internal table (`GT_BSIS`) which has around 300K records, whose clearing key value should be the same for both internal tables (`1:N` cardinality).
3. It then inserts those common records to the third standard internal table (`GT_L2_DISP`) for further processing/display.

Code:

```
LOOP AT <oi_table> ASSIGNING <oi_line>.
  ASSIGN COMPONENT 'BOX' OF STRUCTURE <oi_line> TO <oi_field>.
  IF <oi_field> = 'X'.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT 'CLEARING_KEY' OF STRUCTURE <oi_line> TO <oi_field>.
    LOOP AT gt_bsis WHERE clearing_key = <oi_field>.
      MOVE-CORRESPONDING gt_bsis TO gt_l2_disp.
      APPEND gt_l2_disp.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Here, `<oi_table>` contains data for first level ALV output and `GT_BSIS` would contain data for 2nd level ALV output.

My understanding :

If we can fill up standard internal table `GT_BSIS` and marking/passing 'X' to a column (say `FLAG`) in `GT_BSIS`, **while user is selecting rows from ALV first level output**, it would help in performance as ONE `LOOP .. ENDLOOP` could be avoided.

An indexed internal table may also be an option. Please suggest a way to improve the performance.

NB: our SAP System is ECC, ABAP 7.31, so please do not propose inline code/declaration.

Comment: Gt_bsis has to be TYPE SORTED table with the field clearing_key

Comment: I have edited your question, could you verify that I didn't introduce errors, especially 1) "12 million mili seconds" -> "200 minutes" (3 hours and 20 minutes) and 2) "would NOT require" -> "could be avoided" (by the way, I don't understand what this sentence exactly means).

Comment: If you know that the "indexed internal tables" exist and are related to performance issues (that's right), why don't you try to use them?

Comment: Use BSIS db hints here [1](https://answers.sap.com/questions/4593245/optimize-a-bsis--bseg-query.html), [2](https://answers.sap.com/questions/719932/how-to-query-from-bseg-table-efficiently.html), [3](https://answers.sap.com/questions/6911445/bsis-performance-is-very-slow-in-query.html) and do not use itab [implicit header lines](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenitab_header_line.htm) which is strongly prohibited and discouraged now

Comment: And thinks twice if you need dynamics in your report (<oi_table>), because it slows down a little too

Comment: Hello Sandra, Yes, it is about 4 Hours, i.e. in fact more than 12 Millions Milli Seconds

Comment: Sandra, Indexed Internal Table, as I mentioned, in this case, not helping ,

Comment: Hello Suncatcher,  You are Right, this Program was Created by Someone Else earlier and I need to do a Performance Improvement now,

Comment: Would there be a way in ECC(ABA 7.31), when we Select ALV Output Rows(that comes from a Dynamic Internal Table(<oi_table>), 
it can Update another Standard Internal Table GT_BSIS, (Passing a mark say 'X' into a Field say FLAG) for those Rows comparing a Common Field "Clearing_Key",

Comment: Thus the option I may be looking for is Either Specific Coding on FM "REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY" OR "Have another Internal Table similar to <oi_table> with User Marked Rows in  
ALV First Level Output -> then Select Related Records from another Internal Table GT_BSIS using a common Field -> Then Get those Rows from GT_BSIS to pass to another Standard Internal Table". 
There could be about 400K Records in both the Internal Tables, <oi_table> as well as in GT_BSIS and hence Performance Issue is a Factor,  Appreciate your Response, Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but reversing the loops might help you somewhat. In theory this should reduce exponential growth of iterations when the 2 tables grow.

I think reversal might help because you don't appear need `<OI_TABLE>` for anything beyond filtering, but you are looping over it anyways. That means both looping over more rows AND you sometimes might invoke a full scan of `GT_BSIS` if no no corresponding key exists (I'm not entirely sure if loops make use indexing).

```
sort <oi_table> by ('CLEARING_KEY'). "Only if table isn't already a sorted table
Loop at GT_BSIS assigning <ls_bsis> where "Assigning! Don't make copies of each row on each iteration, if you can help it
    read table <oi_table> ASSIGNING <oi_line> with key ('CLEARING_KEY') = <ls_bsis>-clearing_key binary search. 
    check sy-subrc = 0. 
    assign component 'BOX' of structure <oi_line> to <oi_field>
    if <oi_field> = 'X'.
      MOVE-CORRESPONDING <ls_bsis> TO gt_l2_disp.
      append ls_l2_disp to gt_l2_disp.
    endif.
endloop.
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zero, Thank you so much Zero for your Response and Valued Feedback, Appreciate, I have done it and here is the Code Below, which I have used. Performance/Runtime is Reduced Drastically from 210 Minutes to well Below 5 Minutes for about 340K Records for Both those Internal Tables,

```
DATA: git_ibsis TYPE HASHED TABLE OF modbsis_layout1 
                     WITH UNIQUE KEY clearing_key belnr buzei,
      gwa_ibsis LIKE LINE OF git_ibsis.    

FIELD-SYMBOLS : <gfs_ibsis>     LIKE LINE OF git_ibsis.

DATA : lv_clkey(12)   TYPE c,
       lv_box(3)      TYPE c.

       lv_clkey = 'CLEARING_KEY'.   
       lv_box   = 'BOX'.

         SORT : ibsis BY clearing_key belnr buzei,
                <oi_table> BY ('BOX') ('CLEARING_KEY').

         LOOP AT ibsis.
           MOVE-CORRESPONDING ibsis TO gwa_ibsis.
           INSERT gwa_ibsis INTO TABLE git_ibsis.
           CLEAR : gwa_ibsis, ibsis.
         ENDLOOP.

         SORT : git_ibsis BY clearing_key belnr buzei.

         LOOP AT git_ibsis ASSIGNING <gfs_ibsis>.
           READ TABLE <oi_table> ASSIGNING <oi_line> WITH KEY  
                      (lv_box)   = gc_x
                      (lv_clkey) = <gfs_ibsis>-clearing_key BINARY SEARCH.
           IF sy-subrc = 0.
             MOVE-CORRESPONDING <gfs_ibsis> TO zvxl100.
             APPEND zvxl100.
           ENDIF.   
         ENDLOOP.
```

***Note*** : Used Hashed Internal Table,

**Performance / Runtime is Reduced from 210 Minutes to Well Below 5 Minutes,**